# Le Chatelier's principle and energy minimization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, equilibrium

In Callen's "Thermodynamics" in section 8.5 he asks us to imagine some perturbation $dX$ of an extensive parameter of a system in contact with a reservoir that acts to hold fixed the intensive parameter $P$ associated with $X$.

As a result of the perturbation $P$ changes by $dP = \frac{dP}{dX}dX$.

The system now displaced from equilibrium, he asks how $P$ will further change as the system evolves towards new equilibrium. By asserting that the system evolves along a path of decreasing total energy (system and reservoir) at constant total entropy he shows that stability requires that $P$ move in a direction opposite to $dP$, this proving Le Chatelier's principle.

My trouble is with the assertion that from the perturbed state the system should evolve towards decreasing total energies. The entire system being closed, energy should be conserved, with equilibrium being achieved through entropy maximization.

I'm not crazy, am I? Perhaps an alternative thermodynamic description/proof of Le Chatelier's principle would clear up my confusion.

Comment: you have said there is perturbation, hence the system is not closed

Comment: If, following the perturbation, we assume the system is still subject to further perturbations then we can't say anything about its evolution. It only makes sense to assume that the system then evolves without external influence. 

We could also assume no external influence and just consider a small fluctuation in a simple system and ask about the evolution of the fluctuation. In this case the system is closed for all times.

Comment: (1) first stage equilibrium, (2) then perturbation (3) followed by relaxation to equilibrium. At (2) the system is not closed, it is closed during (3) relaxation but that starts from a different state from (1) that has been changed by the perturbation leading to (2).

Comment: yes I agree completely. but starting from (3) energy is conserved so we should not argue that the state evolves towards lower total energy as I believe Callen does.

Comment: It seems that Callen is assuming that the system is under constant temperature and pressure in that section.  So the system is not closed at all.  This assumption is indeed a bit unusual.  If you like, [Landau's version, Statistical Physics, Sec. 22](https://archive.org/stream/ost-physics-landaulifshitz-statisticalphysics/LandauLifshitz-StatisticalPhysics#page/n73/mode/2up) may be reasonable.

Comment: In his proof he invokes energy minimization of the system and bath jointly.

Comment: I guess the answer lies in the previous section 8-2, there Callen actually showed a contraposition of the entropy maximization principle, which says if the total entropy and volume of the system and bath are held constant, then the total energy of the system and bath must be minimized.  Now the constant total entropy assumption is mainly a _mathematically_ but not physically convenient assumption.  Because, in order to make the total entropy a constant, we have to assume that the larger system (system + bath) is _thermally isolated_, i.e., the larger system is not closed.